# Regex - printable ASCII that not contain some chars (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find a Regex, that allows ***printable ASCII chars*** except - " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >
The string length must be 1-25

This will work:

```
/^[^\\[\]\:\;\|\=\,\/+\*\?<>\"]{1,25}$/
```

But it will match also **non-ASCII** chars

Comment: Are you sure a single regex is the right solution for your problem? If you are, that's fine; the regex is easy enough to write, but sometimes writing code can be more readable....

Comment: All ASCII or only printable ones? `[ -~]`? Also, what is the regex library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?:(?![:[\];|\\=,\/+*?<>"])[ -~]){1,25}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fScSMM/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - outer grouping to enable matching a *quantified* lookahead-restricted ASCII char range

  - `(?![:[\];|\\=,\/+*?<>"])` - the next char cannot be one defined in the character class (`:`, `[`, `]`, `;`, `|`, `\`, `=`, `,`, `/`, `+`, `*`, `?`,
    `<`, `>` and `"`)
  - `[ -~]` - any printable ASCII
- `){1,25}`  - 1 to 25 occurrences
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Why you need '?:' ?  it's looks it's working without it, can please give an example why you need it?

Comment: @cheziHoyzer It works slightly slower when you use a *capturing* group since the regex engines writes the captured value to a separate memory buffer so that you could reference that value either from the pattern or the replacement string. To group a pattern in order to quantify it, a [*non-capturing* group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-a-question-mark-followed-by-a-colon) is a much more natural choice.